# Laravel Auth Validation Message

Tags: laravel, authentication

i did something in laravel project coz of which i am getting this type of validatoin message.[image]

How to fix it.?

Comment: Can you show us your login view ? (Also show your image with ![image][1] )

Comment: You need to see the code.?

Comment: You probably removed translation files or set the application language to a language that hasn't got translations.

Comment: @NitinSrivastava Yes that's easier for us to help you, if you show the concerned code.

Comment: it;s the default code that laravel gives. i did something config->app file

Comment: What have you done in the config/app.php file ?

Comment: that's the confusion. i did many changes in many files.  Basically where ever there was code which used to get data from env file i replaced the second string.     eg:  'name' => env('APP_NAME','Laravel'), i modified to 'name' => env('APP_NAME'),

Comment: Like @Jerodev said, you probably removed translation file, or changed the application language.

Comment: thanks @Jerodev, for pointing the fault.   i changed the lang from en to en-Gb.    Problem Solved